# Explicit vs implicit call of ToString()

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is there any benefit in calling the ToString() method on a string builder when the method call accepts the type object as it's parameter?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");

System.Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

OR

```
System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

From what I know the WriteLine takes an object as an overload, my guess is the ToString() method is then called on the object, which then calls the StringBuilder.ToString() method and returns the expected string value.

So again, is there any benefit in explictly calling ToString()? Could you please justify your answer?

Comment: Presumably there would be an additional method call involved, but you'd imagine that it would just be compiled out anyway - the overhead for it would be tiny if it even exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"my guess is the ToString() method is then called on the object"*

If you look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) you see that there is no overload that consumes a `StringBuilder` directly, so [the one which accepts anything(`object`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) is used.

So your guess was correct, it will just call `ToString`.

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the
>   **ToString** method of value is called to produce its string
>   representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard
>   output stream.

Then i would prefer to call it myself since it's more readable and you gain nothing by passing the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

The only benefit is that it is clear what you're doing. If you can state something explicitly do it - it makes the code more readable.

Comment: That is a *very* broad statement right there. In fact, with an appropriate name for the `StringBuilder`, I'd say that it's not necessary - `WriteLine(OutputText)` is not less clear than `WriteLine(OutputText.ToString())`

Comment: I disagree and the point of the `WriteLine` overload is that you don't have to call `ToString` explicitly. In the first case, it is perfectly clear that he wants to print the content of the string builder.

Comment: Probably on this level of detail it's a matter of opinion. You're probably right that with a good name in this simple situation this could be enough, if the scope is small. However, if it would be an instance variable then calling it "OutputText" would be a bit misleading, because it's not a "text" - it's a text (string) builder.

Comment: @Jeff: because the point of the answer us about the clarity, it depends a lot on the variable name. With variable name `OutputText` the intention is clear, so you really don't need to call `ToString()`. [However why would you call a `StringBuilder`-typed variable `OutputText`? It's _not_ the output text, texts are usually immutable in .NET.] On the other hand, if the variable is called `sb`, I'd prefer seeing `.ToString()` for better readability.

Comment: @Vlad That's fair. However, you're confusing the semantic *idea* of "text" with the language-specific implementation that is immutable. There's no reason that a string-builder (something made up to get around the immutability of .net's string type) can't be considered as text. That's getting too caught up in detail, imo. And yeah, `sb.ToString()` is fine, though I'd argue that anyone who knows `.ToString()` will know `.writeline` just as well.

Comment: @Jeff: I fully agree, if the output text is represented as a `StringBuilder`, it has to be called so. Names are important! I take my note in square brackets back.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any benefit in explicitly calling ToString()?

Console.WriteLine(object) will first check if the object is null and if so simply output an empty line. Calling ToString on a null object will result in a NullReferenceException.

So WriteLine(object) has built in null-safety, and the result for null will be the same as a non-null object that outputs an empty string.  Depending on the context, that null safety could be convenient, or it could cause undesired behavior.

In short, it's more beneficial to call ToString() if you **don't** want a NullReferenceException to be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no benefit. Tools with good static analysis capabilities like ReSharper will actually let you know that the call is redundant and can be safely removed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on tools you could use? I've seen people talk about using Reflector to determine whats going on. How can I know without using ReSharper? Perhaps something that's built in to Visual Studio.

Comment: You've basically just covered the ways to find out: 
1) Use a reflector tool to look at the framework code
2) Use a tool that performs static analysis on your code